# How does using a package with the same name grant me access to another source folder's files?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I have noticed that if I create a package in my "src" folder called "com.johnhoffman.myproject" and a package also with this name in another source folder called "test," all classes in the "test" source folder can access classes from my "src" folder.

Why is that? Even if both packages have the same name, they are still different packages, right? Hence, why should one package be able to access another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, they ARE the same package.

The "src" portion of the path is not included in the package name, and neither is the "test". Eclipse just uses that to differentiate which classes are for testing, etc.

This is useful, for example, when your testing classes want to print package-accessible information for debugging without using reflection (which can get really messy).

Comment: Thank you! What is reflection?

Comment: JavaTut "Reflection" Trail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: Basically, you can edit all the stuff associated with classes, methods, and fields. For instance, you can make any private field into public with Field.setAccessible(), then Field.get() (assuming it is not a primitive).

Answer (score 2):

If they are in the same classpath, then they *are* in the same package if they have the same package name